# Saving lines from cat to array

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to read numbers from .txt file and than store it into array so I can sort them using bubble sort.

I was trying something like that:

```
input=$1
readIt=`cat $1`
array=${#readIt[*]}
```

When I was trying to display it using echo it is displaying good, but when I'm trying to sort it, then it doesn't work.

Any help, please?

EDIT: I checked other topics, but I want to solve this problem using "cat" to understand it in easier way as beginner.

Answer (score 2):

Use `readarray` (`bash` 4+)

```
readarray -t array < "$1"
```

or a loop (prior to `bash` 4):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  array+=("$line")
done < "$1"
```

Comment: It's not doable using cat function? Since I'm fresh into bash I was trying to use some simple methods.

Comment: If your file consists of nothing but numbers, you can get away with `array=( $(cat "$1") )`, but that approach assumes that line breaks are no more significant than other whitespace that may appear on a line (that is, you aren't getting one line per element in your array) and that there are no characters that subject you to pattern expansion (like `*` or `?`) in the file.

Comment: `cat` is not a function; it is a entirely separate program from `bash`.

Comment: But how can I than bubble sort it? using array[i] and array[j]? Is possible?

Comment: Yes, but that's en entirely separate question.

Comment: Hm by using that your suggestion I got an error about "too much arguments" when comparing readIt[i] -gt readIt[j]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126345/discussion-between-hc1122-and-chepner).